# How can I draw a continuous line on map using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet

I have a map and I have drawn two points and drawn a line between two points using leaflet Polyline method [Leaflet Polyline](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline) As of now, my code works fine but how I want to show is like a line between Point A to Point B then from Point B to Point C.. so on.
Here is my current code [my current code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vg5tl5) which draws line between 2 points perfects but its always between Point A and Point B.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Note: Map may not be visible due to some issues but you can click on map to pick points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `_firstLatLng = _secondLatLng` when you add the polyline:

```
  if (_firstLatLng && _secondLatLng) {
    // draw the line between points
    L.polyline([_firstLatLng, _secondLatLng], {
      color: 'red'
    }).addTo(_map);
    _firstLatLng = _secondLatLng;
    
    refreshDistanceAndLength();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you brother @Falke Design. Means a lot.

Comment: Done that. Bro any idea how to get distance between two points in kilometers? I am able to get it using distanceTo() method but it's giving me in meters? Appreciate the help and your time.

Comment: divide it through 1000

Comment: Thank you man. one last last thing. How to implement screenshot feature? Like I want user to right click on my map and show an option called "Take screenshot" and then user will click and screenshoot will be generated for that particular section of the map? Any plugin need to be used to do it?

Comment: Look into https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport

Comment: Thank you brother. I appreciate your time and help. Means a lot. May you receive something amazing this weekend which will change your life completely in a best possible way. Thank you again

Comment: hey bro, could you please help me with this if you got a little time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232452/how-to-disconnect-a-polyline-between-a-series-of-markers-and-start-a-new-one-in
Thank you