# How to disconnect a polyLine between a series of markers and start a new one in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, leaflet, maps

I am using leaflet. I can add markers on my map and connecting them with polyLine method. Here is the link to my [current code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-csajuo). As of now, the way code is working is, you can start from point A and then to point B and then to Point C and so on. So it's a continuous chain of points which are connect with Polyline. What I want is I want to give an option to the user like on press escape or having a click option on div. I want user to break this chain and let him start over adding markers on the map keeping the earlier ones laid on the map. So this way I want user to add wherever he want's to add and disconnect either by pressing escape or by clicking on div tag and start a second series and then third and so on. Please have a look on my code.

```
 //Plotting the points
 map.on('click', function(e) {

  if (!_firstLatLng) {
    _firstLatLng = e.latlng;
    _firstPoint = e.layerPoint;
    L.marker(_firstLatLng).addTo(_map).bindPopup('e.latlng + '<br/>' + e.layerPoint).openPopup();
  } else {
    _secondLatLng = e.latlng;
    _secondPoint = e.layerPoint;
    L.marker(_secondLatLng).addTo(_map).bindPopup(e.latlng + '<br/>' + e.layerPoint).openPopup();
  }
 // connecting two points
  if (_firstLatLng && _secondLatLng) {
    // draw the line between points
    L.polyline([_firstLatLng, _secondLatLng], {
      color: 'blue'
    }).addTo(_map);
    _firstLatLng  = _secondLatLng
  }
})
```

Could you please help me with the logic here?

How can I implement it?

Any help is appreciated. I thank you.

Note: Map may not be visible due to some issues but you can click on map to pick points

Comment: You can remove a layer (such as a polyline) with its `.remove()` method or `map.removeLayer(line)`. You can add a `click` listener on the line itself that does that once clicked.

Comment: What is line here?

Comment: Bind the polyline to a variable so you can store it and use it later, e.g.`let line = L.polyline(...)`.

Comment: Yeah but that removes all the polylines. What I want is to start a new one. For example, I drew A to B. Now we have a line between A and B which is fine and I want it .At this point, I want user to click on div or something so that he can draw new points and polyline gets drawn between them that would be C to D. Could you please help me with this? My stackblitz link is up there.

Comment: whoever is looking for answer:  So basically making your initial variables _firstLatLng and _secondLatLng = undefined. This works.

Comment: @jogo is this question answerd?

Comment: @FalkeDesign yeah bro I solved it. Thank you so much

Comment: @FalkeDesign Hey bro, just in case you get some time, please have a look on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303764/how-to-draw-a-custom-pie-chart-kinda-shapeimage-attached-in-the-desc-using-cr .  I need to build this one and place it on the leaflet. Not able to understand where to start on this one. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @FalkeDesign bro any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755055/how-can-i-make-canvas-leaflet-js-library-compatible-for-angular-9 . I would really appreciate it as I am stuck on this :(

Comment: @jogo sorry I never worked with angular and I have no idea, how leafet-draw and canvas can work thogether. So I can't help...

Comment: @FalkeDesign sure no problem bro. thank you :)

Comment: @FalkeDesign Hey bro, I am drawing some shapes on leaflet map using createJS I am able to place these shapes based on their coordinates on the map but the problem happens when I zoom in or out. The shapes displaces from their coordinates out floating on the map. I am using custom layer plugin as of now to plot these shapes. 
Can you please give  me a hint or solution to fix this problem? Like when I zoom in or out, my shapes move ? How to fix this problem? Appreciate your time. Thank you. Waiting

Comment: @jogo can you pls create a demo? else it is realy hard to understand and help